# split text by characters (with file_get_contents and file_put_contents)

Tags: php, split, file-get-contents

I have the following code which works exactly as it should:

```
<?php
$text = "text"; $text_ok = urlencode($text);
if(!@file_get_contents("http://site.com/t=".$text_ok))
{
    echo "Error.";
}
else
{
    $data = file_get_contents("http://site.com/t=".$text_ok);
    $file = "texts/".md5($text).".txt";
    if(!file_exists($file)) {
        file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }
?>
Lorem <?php echo $file; ?>"> ipsum
<?php
}
?>
```

The problem is that `http://site.com/t=$text_ok` only works if `$text` is less than 25 characters. I'm wondering if it is possible when `$text` exceeds 25 characters to split into multiple parts and create files like `texts/md5($text)/1.txt`, `texts/md5($text)/2.txt` etc. I hope you understand. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$text = "text";
$split = str_split($text, 25);
$count = 1;
foreach ($split as $s) {
    $text_ok = urlencode($s);
    if (!@file_get_contents("http://site.com/t=" . $text_ok)) {
        echo "Error.";
    } else {
        $data = file_get_contents("http://site.com/t=" . $text_ok);
        $file = "texts/" . md5($text) . "/" . $count . ".txt";
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            file_put_contents($file, $data);
        }
        ?>
        Lorem <?php echo $file; ?>"> ipsum
        <?php
    }
    $count++;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$part` will always be the first 25 characters of the string, `$rest` will contain everything after.

Comment: Ah okay, I've edited my example. It will split the string at each 25 characters.